# jQuery and Moo Tools

Tags: jquery, mootools, joomla3.0

Been fighting with a conflict between jQuery and MooTools (inherited this mess, and trying my best to quickly resolve the issues)

Have a Joomla site that is requiring the Autocompleter (http://digitarald.de/project/autocompleter/), and got it to the point of where it can't find for mootools $merge

Live URL: http://www.michiganhomecareguide.com/index.php?option=com_mhcg&view=search&Itemid=149

On the page, jQuery first, then jQuery.noConflict();, then load mootools, then autocomplete files, then the Joomla drops the Autocomplete code onto the page.

[load order http://www.michiganhomecareguide.com/templates/mhcg01/js/loadorder.PNG](http://www.michiganhomecareguide.com/templates/mhcg01/js/loadorder.PNG)

http://www.michiganhomecareguide.com/templates/mhcg01/js/loadorder.PNG

order in which the files are currently being loaded.

[chrome debug error http://www.michiganhomecareguide.com/templates/mhcg01/js/merge.PNG](http://www.michiganhomecareguide.com/templates/mhcg01/js/merge.PNG)

http://www.michiganhomecareguide.com/templates/mhcg01/js/merge.PNG

This is a screen grab of the error location from Chrome.

What I am trying to sort out is, is there an alternative to the $ to access the mootools $merge functionality?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: $merge is nothing to do with a conflict, your script is using really old mootools api. http://mootools.net/docs/core/Core/Core#Deprecated-Functions:merge -> now `Object.merge`. is this Harald's autocompleter? it's 4-5 yrs old ... use the mootools compat build or refactor as per upgrading guide from 1.2 to 1.4.5